# FBX shaders messing with materials when importing to Blender

Tags: materials, shaders, import, .fbx

I'm trying to import an FBX model to Blender and when I do, it just completely messes up the materials. I know what shaders the model uses (which are custom) but I want to know if there's a way I can change the shader within Blender/change whatever to stop the materials to look like this.

[image: Broken Model Materials]

Answer (score 0):

That color only indicate that Blender cannot find a texture map.

1. Has been moved to a different location
2. The connection is lost
   If there are more than one texture image if you reload the texture looking in the proper folder, Blender will update the rest of the texture locations.